# Unable make a JNI call to Java getter from C code

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I can successfully make JNI calls to java. I fetch an array from JNI call. But I cannot access elements inside this array.

Following is my C code:

```
void jniInvokeMethod(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject object) {
    jstring folderName = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "");
    jstring token = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Second string");

    jmethodID getFolderContents = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getFolderContents", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Lcom/labsite/rest/model/FolderOrFile;");
    if (getFolderContents != 0) {
        printf("getFolderContents found\n");
    }

    jobjectArray folderContents = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, object, getFolderContents, folderName, token);
    printf("%s\n", folderContents);

    jobject* elem = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, folderContents, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, folderContents); i++) {
        jobject folderContentObj = elem[i];
        //jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, folderContentObj);
        jclass folderOrFileCls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Lcom/labsite/rest/model/FolderOrFile;");
        jmethodID getSizeMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, folderOrFileCls, "getSize", "()J");
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, folderContentObj, getSizeMethod);
    }
}
```

Following is the method I call from C:

```
public class Client {
  public FolderOrFile[] getFolderContents(String folderName, String token) {
  ...
  }
}
```

Visual Studio Debugger stop when `(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, folderContentObj, getSizeMethod)` line is being executed, following error message is provided:

> Exception thrown at 0x0000000058A498ED (jvm.dll) in mirror.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000009.

Following is the class being returned:

```
public class FolderOrFile implements Serializable {
  ...
  private long size;

  public long getSize() { return size;}
  ....
}
```

I am able to invoke `getFolderContents()` methods. But I cannot invoke a getter of an object. What is wrong with `getSize()` invocation? (The same thing applies to other methods of `FolderOrFile` class.

How should I interpret the error message provided by Visual Studio?

Comment: You are indexing a pointer to a single object: `GetObjectArrayElement` returns a `jobject`, not a `jobject*`

Comment: Your comment helped me solve the error. You may post an answer to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake here:

```
jobject* elem = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, folderContents, 0);
```

`GetObjectArrayElement` returns a `jobject`, not a `jobject*`. Since `jobject` is a `typedef` for a different pointer type the code still compiles though (with a warning, so be sure to turn those on if you haven't!). Then later on, when you try to index this pointer:

```
jobject folderContentObj = elem[i];
```

You actually get a more or less random value for the `jobject` (whatever happens to be in memory there), so when you try to use that with `CallObjectMethod`, you get an access violation.

There is no equivalent to [`Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Get_PrimitiveType_ArrayElements_routines) for object arrays (my guess is that this is due do differences in memory layout in the VM internally). So the way to access the elements, is to call `GetObjectArrayElement` on every iteration:

```
jobject folderContentObj = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, folderContents, i);
```

Comment: @John, how can I contact you?

Comment: @Halil I don't want to be contacted.

Comment: Can you provide us paid support?

Comment: @Halil No, I'm currently not in a position to take on any work obligation.

Comment: @Halil Sorry, I wish you the best of luck.